# Diamond-like UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, cornerradius

I am trying to create a UIView with corners like a shape of a diamond, as shown in the picture:

[image: diamond]

I am familiar with rounding off corners:

```
myView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
```

However, I want a different shape.  How could I create this effect? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Override `drawRect:`.

Comment: Sorry, I have never used that method before. Could you please provide me with some sample code? Thanks

Comment: Please read the [View Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503)

Comment: This guide is good, but too big. If you just want to solve this particular problem, use`UIBezierPath`

Comment: I've never really worked with drawing frames etc. Could you help me out with some code?

Comment: Read the section about custom views and using `drawRect:`.

Comment: Check out this great [Demo project](http://oleb.net/blog/2012/02/cgpath-hit-testing/) on Custom shape views and performing hitTest on them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best way to solve a problem like this is by using CAShapeLayer. Here's the kind of thing that would work: paste it into a playground and see how it clips off the corners.

```
import UIKit
import XCPlayground

extension UIView {
    func maskCorners(inset: CGFloat) {
        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x: bounds.origin.x + inset,y: 0))
        path.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMaxX(bounds) - inset,y: 0))
        path.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMaxX(bounds), y: bounds.origin.y + inset))
        path.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMaxX(bounds), y: CGRectGetMaxY(bounds) - inset))
        path.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMaxX(bounds) - inset,y: CGRectGetMaxY(bounds)))
        path.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: bounds.origin.x + inset,y: CGRectGetMaxY(bounds)))
        path.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: 0,y: CGRectGetMaxY(bounds) - inset))
        path.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: 0,y: bounds.origin.y + inset))
        path.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: bounds.origin.x + inset,y: 0))

        let mask = CAShapeLayer()
        mask.frame = bounds
        mask.path = path.CGPath
        layer.mask = mask
    }
}

let diamond = UIView(frame: CGRect(x:0, y: 0, width: 100, height:100))
diamond.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.liveView = diamond
diamond.maskCorners(25)
```

Comment: is it possible you could show me how to create a function with this so I can use it for many views. I have tried myself, but I have not been able to produce the same result.

Comment: Thanks again. This is exactly what I was looking for!